Cardinality of base of mapping space with point-wise convergence topology
Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces, what is the cardinality of the base of $Y^X$ endowed with the point-wise convergence topology? Naively I would think it's $\alpha^\beta$ where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the cardinalities of the respective bases, but I can't seem to justify this.
